# NullPointerException happens on onClick method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I created a class which validates the email format.

```
public class EmailValidator {
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    // regular expression for email validation
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    public EmailValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }

    public boolean validate(final String email) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

By using the above class, I want to implement a code which actually executes the validation and sends out the toast if the email is not a valid format. So I created another code as follows.

RegisterActivity.java

(1) variable

```
EmailValidator validator;
EditText etEmail;
```

(2) onClick method

```
String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
**if(validator.validate(email) == false)** {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email format.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The code so far seems to have no problem, but when I ran it it threw a NullPointerException on the part above. Am I missing something?

If you need to know further about the code, please let me know so that I can update very soon. Thank you!

Update: Here's the logcat.

```
07-07 20:05:30.761      342-342/com.marshall.gruppo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.marshall.gruppo, PID: 342
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.marshall.gruppo.ui.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @TristanWiley Gotcha I just uploaded.

Comment: Can you highlight the line that throws the error?

Comment: You have to initiate the variables...

Comment: Offtop: you can simplify if condition to `if (!validator.validate(email))`. It will not solve the error, it just a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create object of EmailValidator class like this

```
EmailValidator validator = new EmailValidator();
if(validator.validate(email) == false) {
   //do your operation here
}
```

Comment: OMG this was sooo basic!! Shame on me that I missed this basic one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Creating new instance of this class every time you want to validate e-mail address is very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create new class instance every time to validate if it's email. You can place `isValidEmail` in `static` class.

I suggest use this code for your validation:

```
final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

boolean isEmail = isValidEmail(email);
```

With function:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(String text) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text).matches();
    }
}
```

---

In your Activity declarate:

```
private EditText etMail;
```

Then in your `onCreate` method, after `setContentView`

```
etMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Then call method from above as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your Edittext is not declared:

```
EditText etEmail
```

Declare etMail

```
etMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MYEDITTEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add constructor and Throw in try/catch in on click listener and add exception e,  or you can do the if/else with your code

```
EmailValidator validation = new EmailValidator() ;

String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
if (validation.validate(email) == true) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it sent!!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email format.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```